# getxmlschema from DataSet Use sequence insted of choice

Tags: c#, dataset

When I use following Snippet:

```
    static DataTable Table()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable("Prescription");
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

        return table;
    }


        DataSet set = new DataSet("Hospital");
        set.Tables.Add(Table());
        Console.WriteLine(set.GetXmlSchema());
```

The result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema id="Hospital" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="" xmlns:msdata="">
  <xs:element name="Hospital" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:**choice** minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Prescription">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Dosage" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="Drug" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="Patient" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:**choice**>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

In oder to use this xsd file in Excel I have to Replace

```
  <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">...</xs:choice>
```

to

```
  <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">...</xs:sequence>
```

How to set Dataset to get "sequence" instead of "choice" in xsd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any way to change the functionality embedded in GetXmlSchema to suit your needs. Of course you can create a new class derived from Dataset where you write your *special* implementation of GetXmlSchema. Minimally you need just two methods:

```
public class DataSetExcel : DataSet
{
    public DataSetExcel(string dataSetName) : base()
    {
        this.DataSetName = dataSetName;
    }
    public string GetXMLSchema()
    {
        string result = base.GetXmlSchema();
        result = result.Replace("xs:choice", "xs:sequence");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Anf then use this class when you need that functionality

```
DataSetExcel set = new DataSetExcel("Hospital");
set.Tables.Add(Table());
Console.WriteLine(set.GetXmlSchema());
```